# How to use Images in a CostumControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a problem regarding Images in a CostumControl which is written in a seperate Library named "PControls".

Inside that Library I have a folder named "Resources" which contains images "group.png", "filter.png" and "sort.png". When I try to use my control in another project, the images do not appear...

I've allready tried the following:

- All images buildoperations are set to Resource (not Embedded Resource)
- Image Source-Property set to every possible URI (e.g. "/PControl;/component/Resources/filter.png") "../Resources/filter.png" is the only value where VS seems to find the image as there is no error shown

Here is part of my Style - it's basically the style of the standard WPF DataGrid, enhanced by a toolbar which houses buttons that should show the images:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PDataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PDataGrid}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Button Command="{x:Static local:PDataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:PDataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PDataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PDataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PDataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>

                                    <ToolBarTray Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" IsLocked="True">
                                        <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1" >
                                            <Button Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Sort">
                                                <Image Source="../Resources/sort.png" />
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Filter">
                                                <Image Source="../Resources/filter.png" />
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Group">
                                                <Image Source="../Resources/group.png" />
                                            </Button>
                                        </ToolBar>
                                    </ToolBarTray>
                                    ...
```

Comment: Did you read the [pack URI documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I did. And I've tried every possible URI notation I could find in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now!

I'm sure I've allready tried it yesterday, but now the following works:

```
<ToolBarTray Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" IsLocked="True">
    <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1" >
        <Button Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Sort">
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/PControls;component/Resources/sort.png" />
        </Button>
        <Button Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Filter">
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/PControls;component/Resources/filter.png" />
        </Button>
        <Button Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Group">
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/PControls;component/Resources/group.png" />
        </Button>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: Please mark your own question as accepted, by clicking the white tick under the arrows to the left (it will turn into a shiny green tick). It's *very* important for this site to mark answered questions as answered. It's some kind of archiving: it allows old questions to "rest in their final place". :-)

Comment: I know this, but I have to wait another 5 hours before I can mark my own answer as accepted. Don't know why this is necessary... I'm sure this leads to alot of unmarked answers as not everybody will come back after 24 hours to do this.

Comment: Ah, ok then, sorry about that. Yeah, that's what I think, too.